# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'csv_file' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

When I run my code I get these errors:

```
if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
```

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'csv_file' referenced before
>   assignment

views.py

```
import csv, io
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Profile

# Create your views here.# one parameter named request
def profile_upload(request):    # declaring template
    template = "profile_upload.html"
    data = Profile.objects.all()# prompt is a context variable that can have different values      depending on their context
    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order of the CSV should be product_title, sku, slug, image_path, price',
        'profiles': data    
              }
    # GET request returns the value of the data with the specified key.
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template, prompt)    
        csv_file = request.FILES['file']    # let's check if it is a csv file
    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'THIS IS NOT A CSV FILE')    
        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')    # setup a stream which is when we loop through each line we are able to handle a data in a stream
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
        next(io_string)
        for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
            _, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
                name=column[0],
                email=column[1],
                address=column[2],
                phone=column[3],
                profile=column[4]
            )
        context = {}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error, it would be great if anyone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try to initialize the variable `csv_file` with `csv_file = ""` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize the `csv_file` variable at the start of method, or anywhere before assigning or referencing the variable

Comment: The language here could be improved. "initializing" a variable in Python is just a regular assignment, so you therefore don't need to initialize before assigning. Also the word "initialize" in python generally applies to objects, not variables. I.e. the `__init__` magic method

Answer (score 0):

scope of variable is limited here , so define the variable with empty at beginning to use it further as:

```
csv_file = ''// overwrites Empty if value found in condition
if request.method == "GET":   
    csv_file = request.files['file']... //files for FILES as per docs
```

Comment: it's throwing me error: " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' "

Comment: should be empty I guess.....let me know what it shows now....and i have gone through this link that is closer to your Q https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: @Codenewbie what do you think about the code after `return`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because variable is defined only if request method is `GET`. Else if method is `POST` you didn't define it but try to use here:

```
if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
```

Also, it's possible to make this code fail because you defined this variable as a `request.FILES['file']`, where there could be no file in request. You can change this to:

```
csv_file = request.FILES.get('file')
if not csv_file:
    # raise error
```

And finally it's better way to use [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) or forms to validate request data.

Comment: @SatyajitBarik sorry, typo in code - I edited answer.

Comment: now i am getting error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' "  at  data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')

Comment: @SatyajitBarik because obviously there is no file. You're misunderstanding the expected behavious here. By `if not csv_file` you should check if something actually assigned to `csv_file` variable and if not - raise an error, not just ignore this fact an go ahed. To be short - you need to debug your view because most likely there is no file in request.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote more complicated logic over there...

First you should check that if there are any file or not

Then you have to write your condition for `if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):`

**Example :-**

```
def profile_upload(request):    
    # your logic  

    if request.method == "GET":
        csv_file = request.FILES['file']
        return render(request, template, prompt)    
    else:
        csv_file = None

    if csv_file:
        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            # your logic
            return render(request, template, context)
```